# Error getting access token after logging into the angular app using MSAL

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using MSAL in my angular app for authentication purpose. To start off, I used the application in https://github.com/Gimly/NetCoreAngularAzureB2CMsal link as demo app with my tenant I created in azure. After I login, before I make an API call, I am successfully able to get the access token without any issue for the above demo app. The code for getting access token is shown below

```
this.clientApplication =
        new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
            environment.clientID,
            this.authority,
            this.authCallback,
            {
                redirectUri: window.location.origin
            });

public getAuthenticationToken(): Promise<string> {
    console.log(this.clientApplication);
    return this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(environment.b2cScopes)
        .then(token => {
            return token;
        }).catch(error => {
            return this.clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(environment.b2cScopes)
                .then(token => {
                    return Promise.resolve(token);
                }).catch(innererror => {
                    console.error('Could not retrieve token from popup.', innererror);
                    return Promise.resolve('');
                });
        });
}
```

To check what is happening, I logged 'this.clientApplication' before I fetch the token and it has a user as shown in the image below

[image]

Now I am following the same approach and trying to integrate this into my actual angular app. I also enabled logging as mentioned here https://github.com/spottedmahn/NetCoreAngularAzureB2CMsal/blob/error-debugging/ClientApp/app/services/authentication.service.ts

I am able to successfully login into the app. But when I am trying to fetch the access token, I get an error 'User login is required' and there is no 'user' in the 'this.clientapplication' which I am logging in console as shown in below image.

[image]

This seems strange because I am able to successfully login but still getting this error. Please help me out with this.

Comment: I just noticed that I get the above error when the page with API call loads for the very first time after logging in. But when I refresh the page again, I am able to get the token without error and the 'user' which was missing in the first case, is there after the refresh. I am unable to figure out what I am missing when the page loads for the very first time.

Comment: There's a typo in the error ('accees' instead of 'access'), are you sure that's not your own code that throws the error?